# openALPR unable to scan eu2 licence plates

Tags: c#, openalpr

I'm using openALPR library with c# and this is my .config file
I'v done training for my plates but it can't recognize well plates. I've tried to execute in debug mode. 
The result of scanning is without any errors but the first line is not recognized

```
; One-line European style plates

; 35-50; 45-60, 55-70, 65-80, 75-90
char_analysis_min_pct = 0.30
char_analysis_height_range = 0.20
char_analysis_height_step_size = 0.10
char_analysis_height_num_steps = 5

segmentation_min_speckle_height_percent = 0.15
segmentation_min_box_width_px = 5
segmentation_min_charheight_percent = 0.2;
segmentation_max_segment_width_percent_vs_average = 1.65;


plate_width_mm = 141
plate_height_mm = 121

multiline = 1

char_whitespace_between_lines_mm = 10

char_height_mm = 43;80
char_width_mm = 25;53
char_height_mm = 43;80
char_width_mm = 25;53

char_whitespace_top_mm = 12.5
char_whitespace_bot_mm = 12.5

template_max_width_px = 423
template_max_height_px = 363
#template_max_width_px = 117
#template_max_height_px = 65

; Higher sensitivity means less lines
plateline_sensitivity_vertical = 55
plateline_sensitivity_horizontal = 55

; Regions smaller than this will be disqualified
min_plate_size_width_px = 14
min_plate_size_height_px = 12

; Results with fewer or more characters will be discarded
postprocess_min_characters = 6
postprocess_max_characters = 12

detector_file = eu2b.xml
ocr_language = ita

; Override for postprocess letters/numbers regex. 
postprocess_regex_letters = [A-Z]
postprocess_regex_numbers = [0-9]


; Whether the plate is always dark letters on light background, light     letters on dark background, or both
; value can be either always, never, or auto
invert = auto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is correct config must be lowercase and float vars

Comment: which vars should be float? are you sure? because i remember i once checked the code and the plate size, max and min values were integer. thanks!